# Calculate average based on array condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset 'G' with:

- 'OID'
- Array of OID of neighboring objects
- Attribute 'P'

I want to enrich the dataset with average of 'P' of the 'neighbors' of 'OID'

I used a for-loop which works but does not seem very efficient (it will take too long to proces the entire dataset)

```
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM G            
   LOOP
        SELECT
            avg(P) into avg_p
        FROM G
        WHERE OID = any(r.neighbors);
        
        UPDATE G
            SET P_AVG = avg_p,
            WHERE OID = r.OID;
    END loop;
```

any ideas to make this more efficient?

**Example with sample data with P_AVG column as it should to be created.**

```
| OID        | neigbors              | P             | P_AVG         | 
| ---------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| '001A'     | {'002A','004A'}       | 1.5           | 3.5           |
| '002A'     | {'001A','003A','005A'}| 2.5           | 3.5           |
| '003A'     | {'001A'}              | 3.5           | 1.5           |
| '004A'     | {'003A','005A'}       | 4.5           | 4.5           |
| '005A'     | {'002A','004A'}       | 5.5           | 3.5           |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the average for each OID in a single query:

```
select g.oid, 
       avg(g2.p) as p_avg
from g
  join g g2 on g2.oid = any(g.neigbors)
group by g.oid
```

The above returns:

```
oid  | p_avg 
-----+-------
001A | 3.5000
002A | 3.5000
003A | 1.5000
004A | 4.5000
005A | 3.5000
```

That query can be used as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update g
  set p_avg = t.p_avg
from (  
  select g.oid, 
         avg(g2.p) as p_avg
  from g
    join g g2 on g2.oid = any(g.neigbors)
  group by g.oid
) t
where g.oid = t.oid;
```